# SQL SERVER educacional tem menos recursos?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa tarde Pessoal,
Hoje me deparei com uma empresa que usa em produção o SQL SERVER Educacional, sei que isso não é correto pois esta ferramenta é apenas para estudo sem fins lucrativos. Porém mesmo assim, gostaria de saber se a versão educacional tem limitações e/ou riscos em relação a outras versões?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, o Sql Server Express possui menos recursos.

A versão Express é focado em aplicações pequena escala, o Standard em aplicações intermediárias, e o Enterprise em aplicações mais robustas.

Acredito que os links abaixo possuem todas as informações que deseja:

[Folheto Comparativo Edições Sql Server 2017](https://download.microsoft.com/download/A/7/0/A7049F57-D68B-49A2-941F-322D364342BC/SQL_Server_2017_Editions_Datasheet.pdf)

[Edições Sql Server 2017](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-pt/sql-server/sql-server-2017-editions)

Answer (score 0):

Não existe uma versão "educacional" do SQL Server.
Existem algumas versões gratuitas, como a Express Edition e o Developer Edition, que podem ser usados para fins educacionais.

E, respondendo a pergunta, elas possuem recursos limitados em relação à Enterprise.

Limitações:

- Quantidade de dados suportada na base é menor
- O número de núcleos é menor
- A quantidade de memória alocada é limitada por instância

Entre outras limitações, porém, para uso educacional ou usar como um pequeno servidor, isso não causa impacto.
Você pode ver as comparações direto no site da Microsoft:

[Edições e resursos SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: João, somente a edição Express que possui as limitações que citou.